# Generating all integers n which n&m==n(m is a given integers) effeciently in C

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

& is bit AND in C.

Example:

```
m= 21(10101)
```

The result:

```
0 16 4 1 20 5 17 21
```

My code:

```
for(int i=0;i<=m;i++) 
    if ((i&m)==i) printf("%d ",i);
```

This will be very slow when m is large.

How to find the result quickly (when answer is very few, such as m=2^30)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
i = 0
repeat
  print(i)
  i = (i + (NOT m) + 1) AND m
until i == 0
```

---

**UPD :**
A bit simpler code:

```
i = 0
repeat
  print(i)
  i = (i - 1) AND m
until i == 0
```

Comment: in second solution :i=0 -> i = m

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is correct, but a bit sparse on detail, so here's *why it works*

Observe that the set `{ n | n & m == n }` is the set of all `n` such that the bits in `n` are a subset of those in `m`. If all those bits were in a group starting at the least significant bit, they could be generated by simply counting from 0 to `m`.

But they're not necessarily grouped thus, there may be empty spaces between the bits. These spaces should be skipped, and how do you make the carry from the incrementing skip those bits?

Well you can make the carry propagate (not exactly skip) through those bits by making them 1. That leaves some garbage in those bits though, which has to be cleared out.

So, first set the bits in the gaps: `i | ~m` (written equivalently as `i ^ ~m` or `i + ~m` because the bits in `~m` are guaranteed to not overlap with any bits in `i`).

Then do the increment (`+1`) and then throw away any garbage left in the gaps: `& m`.

In total: `((i | ~m) + 1) & m`.

---

For the new code, observe that making a borrow from a subtraction propagate through the gaps is easier, because in order for it to propagate the gap should be filled with zeroes, which it already is. The only issue, then, is that some garbage may be left behind in the gaps, which should be cleared out with `& m`, giving, in total, `(i - 1) & m`.

Answer (score 1):

One line code:

```
for(i=m;i;i=(i-1)&m) printf("%d ",i);printf("0");
```